# A way to compute significance of R-squared change across models in a path model, or specifically lavaan?

Tags: regression, structural-equation-modeling, r-squared, model-comparison, path-model

I have a straightforward path model with a single endogenous variable and multiple observed predictors - in other words, a regression.  (I'm doing it as a path model to be able to easily test mediation later).  For now, I really need to know how to test for significance in R2 as I add predictors - the same as you get with the F-change statistic in OLS.  If there's no straightforward way, is there perhaps a formula I could do by hand?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to compare alternative `SEM` models. In this case, I believe that you have to use the *scaled chi-square difference test statistic* (with *Satorra-Bentler correction*): see http://www.statmodel.com/chidiff.shtml and (the original paper) http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11336-009-9135-y. You can perform this test by using `lavaan`'s function `anova()`, which automatically detects the presence of nested models and applies the correction.

For a non-nested models comparison, you could use either one of the following R packages: `nonnest2` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nonnest2) and `simsem` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simsem). Both packages support `lavaan` classes' objects. For `simsem`, in addition to the documentation, you can take a look at non-nested models comparison examples [here](https://github.com/simsem/simsem/tree/master/Conference%20presentations).

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that only works for nested models.  I am looking for a way to add predictors to an existing model and compare the resulting R2 to that of the original model; these two models are not nested.

Comment: @Dimitri: You're correct - for some reason I thought that this is the case. Please see my updated answer. Hope this helps.